# Can I assign an array just by making it equal to another array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array `$x` with nonzero number of elements. I want to create another array (`$y`) which is equal to `$x`. Then I want to make some manipulations with `$y` without causing any changes to `$x`. Can I create `$y` in this way:

```
$y = $x;
```

In other words, if I modify `$y` created in the above shown way, will I change value of `$x`?

Comment: Gosh! This is too easy to test... the required time to write this questions is larger than writing a simple test to know what you want to know.

Comment: You're confusing PHP with python.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Lets give it a try:

```
$a = array(0,1,2);
$b = $a;
$b[0] = 5;

print_r($a);
print_r($b);
```

gives

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 2
)
Array
(
    [0] => 5
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 2
)
```

And the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) says:

> Array assignment always involves **value copying**. Use the reference operator to copy an array by reference.

Answer (score 2):

No, a copy won't change the original.

It would change it if you used a reference to the original array:

```
$a = array(1,2,3,4,5);
$b = &$a;
$b[2] = 'AAA';
print_r($a);
```

Answer (score 2):

Arrays are copied by value. There is a gotcha tho. If an element is a reference, the reference is copied but refers to the same object.

```
<?php
class testClass {
    public $p;
    public function __construct( $p ) {
        $this->p = $p;
    }
}

// create an array of references
$x = array(
    new testClass( 1 ),
    new testClass( 2 )
);
//make a copy
$y = $x;

print_r( array( $x, $y ) );
/*
both arrays are the same as expected
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => testClass Object
                (
                    [p] => 1
                )

            [1] => testClass Object
                (
                    [p] => 2
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => testClass Object
                (
                    [p] => 1
                )

            [1] => testClass Object
                (
                    [p] => 2
                )

        )

)
*/

// change one array
$x[0]->p = 3;

print_r( array( $x, $y ) );
/*
the arrays are still the same! Gotcha
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => testClass Object
                (
                    [p] => 3
                )

            [1] => testClass Object
                (
                    [p] => 2
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => testClass Object
                (
                    [p] => 3
                )

            [1] => testClass Object
                (
                    [p] => 2
                )

        )

)
*/
```